# Como armazenar caracteres especiais em strings e imprimir em arquivos?

Tags: c, string, arquivo, codificação-de-caracteres

Recentemente eu ando trabalhando em um projeto em C que envolve imprimir algumas strings em um arquivo txt. Contudo, quando coloco caracteres especiais e acentos são impressos uns símbolos estranhos, tipo ‡ e Æ. Fiz um código de exemplo mostrando mais ou menos oque eu preciso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

char teste[100];

printf("Frase: "); /*Usei a Frase "Gabriel Fogaça não perguntará em vão" para os testes*/
gets(teste);

printf("\n\nResultado: %s\n", teste);

FILE* arq = fopen("teste.txt", "w+");

    fprintf(arq, "%s", teste);

fclose(arq);

return 0;
```

}

Aliás, quando uso o "setlocale" a impressão fica bugada até no prompt, mas isso é o de menos. O que eu realmente preciso é conseguir imprimir a string no arquivo txt.

Answer (score -2):

O problema é que você está setando o locale para um encoding (provavelmente ISO 8859-1, que usa apenas um byte por caractere) mas o terminal deve estar usando UTF-8 (número variável de bytes por caractere) que é o padrão hoje em dia.

Tente rodar o programa sem chamar a função setlocale.

Comment: Eu rodei sem usar essa função e realmente o resultado no terminal se normalizou, mas no arquivo txt continuam aparecendo símbolos no lugar dos caracteres especiais :(

Comment: É, mas então provavelmente o problema é na configuração de charset do seu editor, que não está UTF-8. Não é culpa do seu programa.

Comment: Aaah entendi. Vou tentar mudar as configurações então. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Consegui trocar as configurações do editor e agora o charset está em UTF-8. Ainda assim o erro continua :(